# BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `heroku create $YOUR_APP_NAME --region eudefaults`

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Showing /Users/moritzvonbuchwaldt/code/mobuffon/rails-mister-cocktail/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #10 raised:

BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `heroku create $YOUR_APP_NAME --region eudefaults`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
Rails.root: /Users/moritzvonbuchwaldt/code/mobuffon/rails-mister-cocktail

After i pushed my code to heroku i couldn’t use my localhost anymore and when pushing to heroku the precompiling of the assets fails. `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

Any suggestions on what could be going wrong with my app?

Comment: What does `/Users/moritzvonbuchwaldt/code/mobuffon/rails-mister-cocktail/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` line #10 look like?

Comment: Try to full text search your project for `heroku create`.  It sounds you might have that somewhere it doesn't belong.  Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the command heroku create $YOUR_APP_NAME --region eudefaults should not be in your rails code. That is meant to be run in your terminal to create an app in Heroku.